# How do I pass a specific number of characters from an istream to an ostream

Tags: c++, stl, istream, ostream

I have an istream (ifstream, in this case), and I want to write a specific number of characters from it into an ostream (cout, to be specific).

I can see that this is possible using something like istream.get(), but that will create an intermediate buffer, which is something I'd prefer to avoid.

Something like:

```
size_t numCharacters = 8;
ostream.get(istream, numCharacters);
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks for reading :)

Edit: added c++ tag
Edit: fixed title :/

**New Edit:**

Thanks very much for the answers guys. As a side note, can anyone explain this weird behaviour of copy_n? Basically it seems to not consume the last element copied from the input stream, even though that element appears in the output stream.  The code below should illustrate:

```
string test = "testing the weird behaviour of copy_n";
stringstream testStream(test);

istreambuf_iterator<char> inIter( testStream );
ostream_iterator<char> outIter( cout );

std::copy_n(inIter, 5, outIter);
char c[10];
testStream.get(c,10);
cout << c;
```

The output I get is:

> testiing the w

The output I would expect is:

> testing the we

Nothing in the docs at cppreference.com mentions this kind of behaviour.  Any further help would be much appreciated :)

My workaround for the moment is to seek 1 extra element after the copy - but that's obviously not ideal.

Comment: How about [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) together with [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: you surely meant `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` and `std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>`. Especially the input side is important as `std::istream_iterator<char>` would skip spaces. Also, the `...buf...` versions are more efficient as they don't create a `sentry` for each object.

Comment: Thanks guys - this seems to be working for me :) If one of you wants to post it as an answer I'll be happy to give you the tick.

Comment: Re. your edit, check whether `get` succeeded or not.

Comment: The problem you noticed seems to be an underspecification in the standard: the standard states that `n` elements are copied but it _doesn't_ state that the input and output iterators need to be incremented `n` times! Looking at the implementation in libstdc++, for example, shows that the source isn't incremented `n` times! For other iterator categories than InputIterator that doesn't matter but for InputIterator it does.

Comment: It's very strange behaviour if you ask me. I looked into the ms implementation of stl and it takes care to increment the dest iterator after the copy, but doesn't bother with the input iterator (so it gets left at the last element copied). Something to watch out for, I guess. Again, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to avoid copying the bytes if you want to limit the number of characters *and* you want to be efficient. For a slow version without a buffer you can use `std::copy_n()`:

```
std::copy_n(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in),
             std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
             std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(out),
             n);
```

I'd be pretty sure that this is quite a bit slower than reading a buffer or a sequence thereof and writing the buffer (BTW make sure to call `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)` as it is otherwise likely to be really slow to do anything with `std::cout`).

You could also create a filtering stream buffer, i.e., a class derived from `std::streambuf` using another stream buffer as its source of data. The filter would indicate after `n` characters that ther are no more characters. It would internally still use buffers as individual processing of characters is slow. It could then be used as:

```
limitbuf buf(in, n);
out << &buf;
```

Comment: Why would this be slower?

Comment: @Etherealone: I'm not sure what _this_ is. However, processing individual characters is slower than processing characters in bulk. When using `std::copy_n()` conceptually each character is processed individually which amounts to: check if there is a character, get it, adjust the stream buffer's that to indicate that was consumed, check if there is space in the output where to stick the character, stick it there, adjust the stream buffer to indicate that there is one more character. For buffers these checks are made once for a sequence of characters and the CPU will copy groups of characters.

Comment: In principle, an implementation could do something fancy for `std::copy_n()` for segmented sequences: get the stream buffer's buffers from the streambuf iterators and copy directly between those. However, the only implementation I'm aware of which did some optimizations along these lines is the one I created and it doesn't do this optimization for `std::copy_n()`. I'm not in the position to measure the differences rigth now but I wouldn't be surprised that using buffers explicitly is an order of magnitude faster (for in-memory source and destination streams).

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer @DietmarKühl! This is mostly working for me. If you have a sec can you take a look at my edit to the question above. I'm seeing some weird behaviour from copy_n.